# Add legend to Chart in react-chartist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chartist.js

I installed plugin chartist-plugin-legend. I want to add legend to my chart, but get the error 'Chartist' is not defined  no-undef. How i can add the legend to chart?

```
import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist';
import ChartistTooltip from 'chartist-plugin-tooltips-updated';

const options = {
 
  plugins: [
    Chartist.plugins.legend(),
    ChartistTooltip({
      anchorToPoint: false,
      appendToBody: true,
      seriesName: false,
    }),
  ],
};

<ChartistGraph
          className='ct-chart-line'
          data={data}
          options={options}
          type='Line'
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have imported the Chartist library. You would need to add this to your project with `npm install --save chartist` and `import Chartist from 'chartist';`.

Comment: thank you, it work. But i get new problem: how do I dynamically assign a legend color to match the color of the line on the graph? Now I have set the color line and legend manually.